# why the bar does not vanish when height is set to 0%

Tags: javascript, css

i am developing a bar graph in css

but when i set the `height` for the bar to be `0%` it does not vanish.
[image: here is the image of the bar graph where the first four bars are set as 0% height]

I want the bars to vanish for the bars with 0% height.
here is css code for bar

```
.bar{
    width:20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

let me know if more information is required

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. One CSS rule isn't enough

Comment: please share your code in code pen or other services for find solution

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) and include enough HTML, JavaScript, and CSS so that others can reproduce the error without having to depend on guesses or external services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `padding`: No matter which `box-sizing` setting you choose, the padding will be *added to* or *part of* the height, which in your case results in a minimum overall height of 40px.

But you can choose to only use left and right padding, then it will become invisible:

```css
.bar{
    width:20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.bar2{
    width:20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar2"></div>
```